# how to show the view contents to be filp from right in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, uianimation

I have iPhone application.

I want that when view is loaded it has subView. Also I want that subView to be loaded like flipping or sliding from left to right in animation.

subView contains UIButton and TextView. I want that subView should load in animation like 
slide from left.

Answer (score 1):

Flipping a view can be done as follows:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animation:^{
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.subView cache:FALSE];
}];
```

Here is my complete code:

```
- (void) flipCard {

if (_isDisplayBackOfCard) {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{

        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.view cache:FALSE];
        [self.backOfCard removeFromSuperview];
        [self.view addSubview:self.frontOfCard];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        _isDisplayBackOfCard = !_isDisplayBackOfCard;
    }];
}
else {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{

        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.view cache:FALSE];
        [self.frontOfCard removeFromSuperview];
        [self.view addSubview:self.backOfCard];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        _isDisplayBackOfCard = !_isDisplayBackOfCard;
    }];
}
```

}

Sliding the view in can be easily achieved by setting the views frame inside an animation block:

```
CGRect _newFrame = CGRectMake(someValueForX, someValueForY, someValueForWidth, someValueForHeight);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{ [self.subView setFrame:_newFrame];}];
```

Comment: I'm guessing you may not be creating & setting the _newFrame variable? I've edited the code above to show you. Simply replace the x,y,width and height values with the ones you require and make sure you reference the correct sub view.

Comment: int someValue for X and y i need to give the values fo the x y of subview

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding subView in `viewDidLoad` method of view and in the `viewDidAppear` method you can use the animation using block statement to give it some animation.

Happy Coding :)

**EDIT 1**

Here I have add scrollView in XIB attach the `IBOutlate` to it. You can programmatically add it to in the `viewDidLoad` method.

At the first I make the View hidden by applying this frame

```
subCatScroll.frame = CGRectMake(320, 0, 91, 436);
```

and on some button click I show it through animation (it is coming from right side edge of iPhone)

```
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender
{
    [Appirater userDidSignificantEvent:YES];
    if(pointer.hidden == YES)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"Move Me To Unhide" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:kAnimationDur];
        subCatScroll.frame = CGRectMake(229,0,91,436);
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        [self configureView];
        pointer.hidden = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"Move Me To Hide" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:kAnimationDur];
        subCatScroll.frame = CGRectMake(320, 0, 91, 436);
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView commitAnimations];        
        pointer.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

Here the `pointer` is one control which is used to decide what to do with scrollView

Comment: If you need some guidance about coding just ask about it :)

Comment: yes i need some code guidance i just want to show and hide and subview with flip side on button click

Comment: first in `viewDidLoad` put the first line and in `viewDidAppear` method put the rest of code but use the `[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{//IF part or to show} completion:^(BOOL finished){//Else part or to hide}];` code to do the animation automatically you can set the duration as you need in place of `.5` :)

Answer (score 0):

OK. As you want to add your **subViews** (not the container view - I had predicted it through your question!) with sliding animation follow the steps -

1. Create `IBOutlet` for your button and textview
2. `synethesize` them in .m file.
3. Write following code -

   ```
       - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
   {

       self.btn.center = CGPointMake(-430.0, 211.0);

       self.txtView.center = CGPointMake(-430.0, 120.0);

       [self addSubview:self.btn andMoveTo:CGPointMake(115.0, 211.0) duration:1.0 option:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear];

       [self addSubview:self.txtView andMoveTo:CGPointMake(40.0, 34.0) duration:1.0 option:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear];

   }


   - (void) addSubview:(UIView*)view 
             andMoveTo:(CGPoint)destination 
              duration:(float)secs 
                option:(UIViewAnimationOptions)option
    {
       [UIView animateWithDuration:secs delay:0.0 options:option
                   animations:^{
                       view.frame = CGRectMake(destination.x,destination.y, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height);
                           }completion:nil];
       [self.view addSubview:view];

   }
   ```